# Which Pancharatra text describes Yogam?

Tags: practice, yoga, pancharatra

Recently while discussing about practice of meditation, I heard that there are five daily activities called Pancakāla Prakriyā which are Abhigamanam, Upadanam, Ijyai, Svadhyayam, and Yogam followed by those who initiated into Pancharatra.

Out of those five, "Yogam" is what I want to know more about since it is related to meditation. I heard that these Panchakala Prakriyas are described in Pancharatra texts but I have no idea in [which Pancharatra text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancharatra#Pancharatra_Texts) these practices are described.

So, I am looking for the text (i.e particular chapter of particular Pancharatra text) describing and explaining "Yogam" practice from Pancharatra texts.

Comment: Is Yogam and Yoga same ?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar I don't know much. I think Keshavan Srinivasan may know.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Yog is the correct word right?  Yogam is the word I have seen in Tamil

Comment: @AkshayS Yogam is also present in sanskrit  - योगं

Comment: @AkshayS Yog is a distortion of word Yogam. Yogam is correct word according to Sanskrit also. It is a misconception that words in Sanskrit end with 'a'.

Comment: Oh thanks @SwiftPushkar was not aware of Yogam in sanskrit because what I was told was Yog is correct word!

Comment: @Sarvabhouma, from what I have learned, yoga is the Sanskrit stem while yogam is either the declined form of the neuter nominative form as well as masculine/neuter accusative case. But what do you mean with yog?

Comment: @GabeHiemstra Yog is from Hindi. Hindi speakers use Yog instead of Yoga. and yes, the word Yogam exists in Sanskrit as accusative case.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Doesn't yoga come from the Sanskrit root yuj, defined as a class 7 verb root? To my understanding, when adding the stem-ending 'a', the final consonant 'j' is voiced to 'g' and the root vowel 'u' gets strengthened to 'o'. Eg., https://sanskrit.inria.fr/MW/213.html#yoga and https://sanskrit.inria.fr/MW/212.html#yuj

Comment: @GabeHiemstra yuj is the verb while 'yoga' is the abstract noun form of the verb. The abstract noun is a masculine noun ending in akaara and declines like the 'rama' word.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is quoted in the Pāñcarātrarakṣā and prescribed in the Dakṣa-smṛti. According to S. M. Srinivasa Chari, regarding Pañcakāla-prakriyā:

> The Pañcakāla-prakriyā of the Pāñcarātra ystem is formulated from out of the religious duties prescribed by the Smṛti texts and fitted into the daily life of a Vaiṣṇava to be observed at five specific times of the day as a form of dedication of one’s life to the service of Viṣṇu...
> [source](https://books.google.nl/books?id=evmiLInyxBMC&lpg=PA312&ots=a_qWpxGf_Q&dq=%22abhigamana%22%20%22prakriya%22&hl=nl&pg=PA312#v=onepage&q=%22abhigamana%22%20%22prakriya%22&f=false)

Then he quotes in a footnote a Sanskrit reference regarding Pañcakāla-prakriyā the quoted from the Pāñcarātra-rakṣa  by Vedānta Deśika :

> (Pāñcarātra-rakṣa p. 108)
> kālapañcaka-vibhāgena abhigamanopādāna ījyāsvādyāyayogarūpa bhagavatsevanaṃ sva-varṇāśrama-jāti guṇa-nimittādi-niyatadharma-sacivaṃ sva-varṇāśrama-jāti guṇa-nimittādi-niyatadharma-sacivaṃ bhagavad-dharma-niṣṭhānāṃ sarveṣāṃ samānam.
> [source](https://archive.org/details/VaisnavismItsPhilosophyTheologyReligiousDisciplineSrinivasaChariS.M.MLBD/page/n181)

Further down the text, he explains the fifth pañcakāla called yoga:

> The fifth and final duty comes after completing the evening prayers and dinner before one goes to rest. This part of the day is called yoga. **What is implied by yoga is that one should contemplate on God until he actually goes to sleep.** At that time the individual should bring himself to feel that his self is resting in God.

According to yet another footnote, he quotes from the Dakṣa-smṛti

> Dakṣa-smṛti (quoted by Vedānta Deśika regarding in Pāñcarātra-rakṣa p. 118)
> sarvopādhi-vinirmuktaṃ kṣetrajñaṃ brahmaṇi nyaset; etat dyānaṃ ca yogaśca...

According to the [English introduction](https://archive.org/details/The.Pancaratra.Raksa.of.Vedanta.Desika/page/n5), the “Pāñcarātrarakṣā is the third work of the Pāñcarātra-āgama”.

Comment: Pancharatra Raksha is a work by Vedantacharya AKA Venkatanatha. That is not a Pancharatra Agama. It is like a commentary to show the significance of Pancharatra agamas.

Comment: Oh my apologies. I thought the English introduction, quoted at the bottom of my post, indicated otherwise. But at least it gives a decent description of yoga in the context of Pañcakāla right?

Comment: No problem. Apology was not needed. Yes, it gives description of Yoga in the context of Pancharatra. If you can find, Vedantacharya cites different Agamas and shlokas in his work. Search and you may find relation to direct Agamas. Another place is looking at Agama Pramanya by Yamunacharya. perhaps the translator wanted to say "third work _on_ Pancharatra Agamas". after Agama Pramanya, Sri Bhashya. Just a guess

Comment: Ok thanks! Luckily, the linked book also contains the Sanskrit text of his work. I will try to give another attempt. I vaguely remember coming across an English translation of Agama Pramanya. Have to look it up too.

Comment: Try to look into Pancharatra  text   called Ahirbudhnya Saṃhitā. May be we will find the description there.